# ActiveDirectory: Can I manually change the DNS records of the domain controllers within an AD domain?

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory, windows-domain

I got some ActiveDirectory DNS issue I hope I can resolve with your help. (The IPs and subnets below are only examples, not the real ones)

DC partner.com [192.168.1.1] <-- NAT 0:65535 --> Firewall [10.0.0.1] <---> Our ADConnect [10.0.0.2]

Accessing LDAP via 10.0.0.1:636 works from our ADConnect to the DC of partner.com and DNS works as well.

The only problem is that the DC of partner.com returns only internal IPs (192.168.1.x) when resolving partner.com.

Our goal is to add (better: only return) the firewall's virtual IP (10.0.0.1) to the DNS response of the DC for partner.com in order for the ADConnect to be able to connect to "customer.com" without getting internal IPs (192.168.1.x) that aren't accessible from the ADConnect.

Is there any easier approach than using split DNS?

Desired:

```
adconnect-shell > nslookup customer.com 10.0.0.1

                  Name:     customer.com
                  Adresses: 10.0.0.1
```

Actual

```
adconnect-shell > nslookup customer.com 10.0.0.1

                  Name:     customer.com
                  Adresses: 192.168.1.x
                            192.168.1.y
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does NAT have to be involved at all? (If the address spaces overlap – have you considered IPv6 as an option?)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but sadly wer'e out of control right behind the customer's firewall. Changing the VPN tunnel to v6 is a nice idea but we don't have the access to do so. :/ 

We can only change the firewall and the DC of our customer.